# Help with RC/RL circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

Hello I'm having a mind blank not understanding what the resistor does on a RC circuit.Why is it needed since why can't the capacitor just charge off the power source. Same question applies for RL,just what does the resistor do. 
Thanks
Image of a series RC circuit
https://www.google.com.au/search?q=RC+circuit&client=ms-android-google&prmd=ivsn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjY9IuHscDSAhWGk5QKHcm7DG0Q_AUIBygB&biw=412&bih=604#imgrc=tLk42EXIjxhHsM:

Comment: Resistors slow down the current. You don't want to fry your components.

Comment: The capacitor can charge directly from the battery or power source  **BUT** you are ignoring the fact that any real world power source has a limitation in the amount of current it can supply. We model this with an 'internal' resistance connected in series with a perfect voltage source. This allows **time** for the capacitor to charge (time constant = CR) because you can't instantly change the voltage across the plates of a capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

The resistor in some cases restricts current.  Voltage on a capacitors can't be changed instantly (and same for current through inductors).  So if you place voltage directly to a cap, there would be a brief high inrush current.  In theory it would be infinite, but in practice, there is some resistance in the wires or traces, in the power source, and in the cap itself.

But most RC circuits are used in AC applications, to filter the input.  For the same reason as mentioned above, if there was no resistor, the cap would be forced to follow the input for the most part.  Adding a series resistor reduces the current and therfore slows down the capacitor charge rate.  So if there are fast (high frequency) transitions on the input (before the resistor), they will be filtered out at the output (after the resistor).

Check out the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit) for a lot more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what a resistor does in an RC circuit.
[image]